# How to POST additional values from inputs outside the form

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I have following form:

```
<table width="250" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" id="inner_table"><tbody><tr>
    <td align="center" style="font: 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;" id="main">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function validateRegistered() {

                    return true;
                }
            </script>
            <form method="post" name="registered" onsubmit="return validateRegistered()">
            <input type="hidden" name="url" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="192.168.96.10">
            <input type="hidden" name="code" value="d">
            <div style="display: none;"></div><br><br>
            <table cellpadding="4" border="0">

                <tbody><tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="data1" style="width: 120px"></td></tr>

                <tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" name="data2" style="width: 120px"></td></tr>

                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="CONNECT" style="font: 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <br>
            <div style="display: none;"></div>
            </form>
```

This is a fixed code that is displayed by tag `<!--LOGIN-->` so I have no access to it what so ever and cannot modify.

Now is there a way I can send values of 2 additional inputs with the existing form upon submit to the destination page?

Comment: Can you modify the validateRegistered() function?

Comment: Unfortunately not it does comes under the same tag

Comment: @Zakaria-Acharki how is that duplicated I don't know but it is annoying when you do mark stuff as duplicated without explaining.

Comment: _is there a way I can add 2 additional inputs to it_ YES, and the other post show you how.

Comment: @Zakaria-Acharki I dont think you understand what I mean? I dont want to add input into the field. I want to send values of the 2 new inputs with the values of the form together to the destination page. My explanation wasnt correct. Sorry

Comment: By adding the inputs to the form the submit action send them _together to the destination page_.

Comment: How can I add them to the form if I can not change the form? I cannot add anything to the tag `<!--LOGIN--> ` I have clearly stated that I cannot modify it

Comment: Can you change it so it doesn't state duplicate as it is not duplicate?

Comment: There's no tag `<!--LOGIN-->` in javascript that is an HTML comment, and has meaning just for you we don't know what you mean when you say i don't have access to the comment_, please try to be more clear.

Comment: Man you are so delusional, I have changed my question upon your request. Said sorry that I wasnt to clear and explained yet again what I mean and you are still not happy seriously? Are you having a bad day or what?

Do you think I am stupid to think that the is this kind of tag in HTML? or do you think I donk know how to add another input into the form??

I cannot edit this tag as mentioned above all I can do is add code above or under in the HTML page.

What is wrong with you people!